# Immersed surface with circle as a boundary

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

Is there a solution or progress of the following problem (maybe old conjecture): Is An immersed surface with constant mean curvature and with a circle as a boundary part of a sphere??. If we replace "immersed" by "embedded" I think the problem was solved by Alexandroff kind of long time ago. Is someone could enlighten about what exactly Alexandroff solves and what is to do, it would help me a lot.

Thanks
Mario

Comment: There are lots of immersed surfaces with boundary the circle.  i think you are asking about immersed surfaces with constant mean curvature.  As far as I know this is still an open question.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't ask the question correctly but it fixes now. Do you know some references or progress about this question?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [this paper of Rafael Lopez](http://www.ugr.es/~rcamino/publications/pdf/art14.pdf) and references therein.

Comment: Right, R. Lopez has several papers with progress towards the conjectures. See theorem 9.2 in the survey I linked to for a comprehensive list of all known conditions which guarantee an immersed surface with circular boundary to be a spherical cap.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your interest is in constant mean curvature surfaces with circular boundary, I found the survey, ["Surfaces with constant mean curvature in Euclidean space"](http://www.ugr.es/~rcamino/publications/pdf/art57.pdf) by R. Lopez to be a great introduction, and it contains the state of the art, and several references.

Hopf proved that the only constant mean curvature closed surfaces of genus 0 are spheres. Alexandrov's theorem says that constant mean curvature closed surfaces that are embedded are spheres. Unfortunately when we allow boundaries both analogs are conjectural:

> **Conjecture 1:** The only constant mean curvature compact surfaces with circular boundary that are topological disks are spherical caps.
>
> **Conjecture 2:** The only constant mean curvature compact surfaces with circular boundary that are embedded are spherical caps.